# How to create collection select with multiple data in rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Any another way to create collection select form with multiple data ?

Example:

```
<%= f.select :name, [['Category A', A]], :price, [['500', 500]], :quantity, [['10', 10]] %>
```

Any Advice? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? To create multiple inputs you have to call `f.select` once for each input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

to manage the collection.

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select